# BeginExecuteReader, EndExecuteReader and multiple results

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.5, sqldatareader

I have method that is asynchronously getting results form my database:

```
internal class CommandAndCallback<TCallback, TError>
{
    public SqlCommand Sql { get; set; }
    public TCallback Callback { get; set; }
    public TError Error { get; set; }
}

public void GetResults(string param, Action<DataTable,DataTable> callback, Action<string> error, Action<string> info)
{
    var conn = new SqlConnection(_connString);
    conn.InfoMessage += delegate(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Errors.Count <= 0) return;
        foreach (SqlError message in e.Errors)
        {
            info(message.State + " " + message.Message);
        }
    };
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = @"GetData";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = param;

    try
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        error(ex.ToString());
        return;
    }

    var ar = new CommandAndCallback<Action<DataTable,DataTable>, Action<string>> { Callback = callback, Error = error, Sql = cmd };
    cmd.BeginExecuteReader(Krok2_Handler, ar, CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}

private static void Krok2_Handler(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var ar = (CommandAndCallback<Action<DataTable,DataTable>, Action<string>>)result.AsyncState;

    if (result.IsCompleted)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader dr = ar.Sql.EndExecuteReader(result);
            var dt1 = new DataTable();
            var dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Load(dr);
            if (dr.NextResult())//I can't access second table in results
            {
                dt2.Load(dr);
            }
            dr.Close();
            ar.Callback(dt1,dt2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ar.Error(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ar.Error("Error calling SQL");
    }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
GetResults("Param value, Success, Error, Info);
```

Everything works fine when my procedure is returning single results, but when I add second select my data reader isn't getting them, probably because when I call `EndExecuteReader` connection is closing.

How can I modify my code to support multiple results so I can pass them to my callback method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested this and I think the problem is here:

```
dt1.Load(dr);
if (dr.NextResult())//I can't access second table in results
{
  dt2.Load(dr);
}
```

From what I can see the the call to Load automatically advances the SqlDataReader to the next record set, so your call to dr.NextResult() will return false.

If you just do this, I think you'll find it works, it did for me:

```
dt1.Load(dr);
dt2.Load(dr);
```

**EDIT:**
 I just checked the source of DataTable.Load and it does call the NextResult method for you:

```
if (!reader.IsClosed && !reader.NextResult())
{
    reader.Close();
}
```

**EDIT2**
When looping SqlDataReader you should use this:

```
if (result.IsCompleted)
{
    try
    {
        List<string> table1 = new List<string>();
        List<string> table2 = new List<string>();
        SqlDataReader dr = ar.Sql.EndExecuteReader(result);

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            table1.Add(dr[0].ToString());//get data from first table
        }

        if (dr.NextResult())//second table
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                table2.Add(dr[0].ToString()); //get data from second table
            }
        }

        dr.Close();
        ar.Callback(table1 ,table2);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ar.Error(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using `EndExecuteReader`, so I think problem is connection closing after calling `SqlDataReader dr = ar.Sql.EndExecuteReader(result);` I think i should check for nextresult. I'll check Your suggestion, but I think I tried that earlier.

Comment: Yeah, I tested using EndExecuteReader too. It definitely works for me, just found some more information, will update the answer.

Comment: thanks for checking. I check that and it works fine when I do DataTable.Load(), but how should I do same thing when I parse every row and add it to list of objects? I'll edit my question in a second

Comment: I had second thing working. It looks that I must use `dr.NextResult()` if I want to iterate table manually and calling `Load` is doing that for me. Please add second usage example and I'll accept Your answer. I'll edit Your answer a bit, so please take a look at it.